# React Native using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, react-native

Is it possible to use `cocoapods` when using `React Native`?

If so, How can I `require` in JavaScript the `pods` projects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It's possible. React Native project is pretty much normal iOS application (In terms of XCode required to build it and quite a lot of React Native internal code is well... Native Obj-C). Since React Native project is already run via xcworkspace, so it's perfectly possible to add Obj-C pods to the ReactNative project.

Since a lot of dependencies used by RN apps are pure javascript rather than Obj-C code, it's more than convenient to keep both dependency systems - Cocoapods (for Obj-C dependencies) and npm (for javascript). Pods are kept in "Pods" directory and npm under "node-modules" and they are not clashing with each other. And it's pretty convenient actually to have different types of dependencies run by different dependency management systems.

UPDATE: by default ReactNative project is .xcodeproj based, but it's easy to convert it to .xcodeworkspace.

I even tried to add React Native itself as Cocoapods dependency and it was sort of working (but some dependencies expected React in the "node-modules" dir so I abandoned it).

Comment: So do we still run our app as react-native run-ios?

Comment: @Learner once you've [added CocoaPods to your RN project](https://shift.infinite.red/beginner-s-guide-to-using-cocoapods-with-react-native-46cb4d372995) subsequent runs of `react-native run-ios` will use the `.xcworkspace` file as opposed to the `.xcodeproj`. You may need to do some tweaking in Xcode to get a clean build depending on the Pod installed before running again from CLI.